# Filtering through JS array of objets and adding the steps value where userName is same

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I am working with JavaScript. This might be relatively easier for professional developers. I want to loop through an array of objects and filter objects with the same userName and add their steps. Following response is the response from my API,

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "UserList": [
        {
            "_id": "5e8c04882e31eb0fa0f240dd",
            "userName": "devyansh",
            "starttime": 1586073600,
            "endtime": 1586077200,
            "steps": 1000,
            "createdTime": 1586234504,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "status": "1",
            "_id": "5e8c04f82e31eb0fa0f240df",
            "userName": "devyansh",
            "starttime": 1586080800,
            "endtime": 1586084400,
            "steps": 47,
            "createdTime": 1586234616,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e8c282e5040a21c1498d95b",
            "userName": "amit",
            "starttime": 1586170800,
            "endtime": 1586131200,
            "steps": 899,
            "createdTime": 1586243630,
            "__v": 0
        },
}
```

I need to filter through this UserList using userName, and add the steps if userName is found to be the same. Here is how I want the response to be,

```
{
   "status": 1,
   "finalList": [
    {
        "totalsteps": 1047,
        "list": [
            {
                "_id": "5e8c04882e31eb0fa0f240dd",
                "userName": "devyansh",
                "starttime": 1586073600,
                "endtime": 1586077200,
                "steps": 1000,
                "createdTime": 1586234504,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "status": "1",
                "_id": "5e8c04f82e31eb0fa0f240df",
                "userName": "devyansh",
                "starttime": 1586080800,
                "endtime": 1586084400,
                "steps": 47,
                "createdTime": 1586234616,
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "totalsteps": 899,
        "list": [
            "_id": "5e8c282e5040a21c1498d95b",
            "userName": "amit",
            "starttime": 1586170800,
            "endtime": 1586131200,
            "steps": 899,
            "createdTime": 1586243630,
            "__v": 0
          ],
    },
  ]
}
```

I already tried this, but not got the expected result,

```
var nameArray = []

  foundData.map((data) => {
     if (!nameArray.includes(data.userName)){
        nameArray.push(data.userName)
     }
  })
  console.log("nameArray",nameArray)
  var finalArray = nameArray.map((data1) => {
     return(  foundData.filter((data) => {
        return data1 === (data.userName)
        }))
     })
  console.log("finalArray",finalArray)
```

Thanks, in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is purely an algorithmic question, and not a very complicated one. Please show your attempts to solve it before asking us to solve it for you :) *Hint: you need to iterate the array in order to achieve it*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group array by `userName` and then sum up `steps` and push element of array inside of `list`. So it can be done [through `reduce` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const result = obj.UserList.reduce((a, {userName, steps, ...rest})=> {
  a[userName] = a[userName] || {totalsteps: 0, list:[]};
  a[userName].totalsteps += steps;
  a[userName].list.push({userName, steps, ...rest});
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

An example:

```js
let obj = {
    "status": 1,
    "UserList": [
        {
            "_id": "5e8c04882e31eb0fa0f240dd",
            "userName": "devyansh",
            "starttime": 1586073600,
            "endtime": 1586077200,
            "steps": 1000,
            "createdTime": 1586234504,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "status": "1",
            "_id": "5e8c04f82e31eb0fa0f240df",
            "userName": "devyansh",
            "starttime": 1586080800,
            "endtime": 1586084400,
            "steps": 47,
            "createdTime": 1586234616,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e8c282e5040a21c1498d95b",
            "userName": "amit",
            "starttime": 1586170800,
            "endtime": 1586131200,
            "steps": 899,
            "createdTime": 1586243630,
            "__v": 0
        }
      ]
};

const result = obj.UserList.reduce((a, {userName, steps, ...rest})=> {
  a[userName] = a[userName] || {totalsteps: 0, list:[]};
  a[userName].totalsteps += steps;
  a[userName].list.push({userName, steps, ...rest});
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Go over UserList, Build an object with keys as "userName".

When userName already exist in object, just update the steps and list.

After the iteration, Get `Object.values()` of above object to get it as array.

```js
const format = arr => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (!res[item.userName]) {
      res[item.userName] = {
        totalsteps: 0,
        list: []
      };
    }
    res[item.userName].totalsteps += item.steps;
    res[item.userName].list.push(item);
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};

const resp = {
  status: 1,
  UserList: [
    {
      _id: "5e8c04882e31eb0fa0f240dd",
      userName: "devyansh",
      starttime: 1586073600,
      endtime: 1586077200,
      steps: 1000,
      createdTime: 1586234504,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      status: "1",
      _id: "5e8c04f82e31eb0fa0f240df",
      userName: "devyansh",
      starttime: 1586080800,
      endtime: 1586084400,
      steps: 47,
      createdTime: 1586234616,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: "5e8c282e5040a21c1498d95b",
      userName: "amit",
      starttime: 1586170800,
      endtime: 1586131200,
      steps: 899,
      createdTime: 1586243630,
      __v: 0
    }
  ]
};

const result = { status: resp.status, finalList: format(resp.UserList) };

console.log(result);
```